# Getting 'E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout' in Kotlin tabbedActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Hi I am beginning with Kotlin and tried to create tabbedActicity with parsed list. I am getting data with retrofit from google APIs.
Then I try to pass it to recycleView.
I tried many ways, but I keep getting error: `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`
Corresponding textView is present in score_row.xml layout and RecyclerView in thirdtab.xml layout.

**thirdTabFragment.kt :**

```
class thirdtabFragment : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ThirdtabBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ThirdtabBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        val apiInterface = APIClient.client.create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        val call = apiInterface.getScore()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Item>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Item>>, response: Response<List<Item>>) {
                Log.d("Success!", response.toString())
                showContenders(response.body()!!)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Item>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Failed Query :(", t.toString())
            }
        })
    }

    private fun showContenders(contenderList: List<Item>) {

        binding.recyclerView.apply{
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@thirdtabFragment)
            adapter = ScoreAdapter(contenderList)
        }
    }
```

**ScoreAdapter.kt :**

```
class ScoreAdapter(private val contenderList: List<Item>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ScoreAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.score_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = contenderList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val contender = contenderList[position]
        holder.contenderName.text = contender.contenderName
    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val contenderName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contenderName_tv)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach the adapter sooner, in the `onCreate` method.
For that make `contenderList` in `ScoreAdapter` public

```kotlin
var contenderList = listOf<Item>()
   set(value){
      field = value
      notifyDataSetChanged()
   }
```

then

```kotlin
//move this code to onCreate
adapter = ScoreAdapter()
binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

Then modify the `onResponse` method

```kotlin
override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Item>>, response: Response<List<Item>>) {
   Log.d("Success!", response.toString())
   adapter.contenderList = response.body()!!

}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I moved it up to onCreate function as you suggested and predefined List, but it still shows the same error.

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: After displaying json in log it shows two errors```2021-09-29 16:18:03.025 16827-16827/com.coza.typ E/Failed Query :(: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 5 column 6 path $.values[0]
2021-09-29 16:18:09.239 16827-16827/com.coza.typ E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout```

Comment: your model classes are probably not accurate. Generate them with json to kotlin classes extension for android studio.